Finding the area of a equilateral triangle with a height of 7cm.
So I am not completely sure how to figure out this question and would love some help.
Here is the question:

To start I looked at the diagram and added in information that I knew.
 I labeled each side “a” as they are all equal.

 I also drew two lines showing that each half of the bottom would be the same length.


So I know each half of the bottom could be written as a/2 (because it is half of a) and using Pythagoras theore we would need to solve for h.
c^2 = a^2 x b^2
So at this point I know to I can plug in the variables.
(a^2) = (h^2) + (a/2)
So this is where I get stuck and would love some help to finish the question! Thanks in advance!

What is the $~\text{cotan}(60^\circ)~$ (i.e. the cotangent function) ?

Using Pythagoras Theorem, we know
$a^2 = h^2 + (a/2)^2$.
Substituting $h=7$ results in
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{3a^2}{4} =& 49\text{cm}^2,
\end{eqnarray}
\begin{eqnarray}
a = \frac{14 \sqrt{3}}{3}\text{cm}
\end{eqnarray}
The area of equilateral triangle is
\begin{equation}
(Area) = ah/2 = \frac{49\sqrt{3}}{3}\text{cm}^2
\end{equation}

Excuse me, but you forgot the units. It's $\frac{49\sqrt{3}}{3}\mathrm{cm}^2$ please.

how did you jump to the 3a^2/4  I am just not sure how to get there from the original formula

@VioletFields $$a^2 = h^2 + (a/2)^2 \implies a^2 - (a/2)^2 = h^2.$$
